# Implement a trait for another trait

Tags: rust

Consider this snippet:

```
struct Foo(i32);

trait MetaTrait {
    fn generic(&self, n: i32);
}

trait MyTrait {
    fn my_method(&self, x: i32);
}

impl MetaTrait for MyTrait {
    fn generic(&self, x: i32) {
        self.my_method(x);
    }
}

impl MyTrait for Foo {
    fn my_method(&self, n: i32) {
        println!("doing something with {}", n);
    }
}

fn my_dynamic_fun<T: MetaTrait + ?Sized>(arg: &T) {
    arg.generic(100);
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo(42);
    my_dynamic_fun(&foo);
}
```

It gives the error:

```
  --> src/main.rs:30:5
   |
30 |     my_dynamic_fun(&foo);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `MetaTrait` is not implemented for `Foo`
   |
```

Instead an explicit type cast works:

```
my_dynamic_fun(&foo as &MyTrait);
```

Probably I've not completely grasped the concept of a trait implementation for a trait ...
but why the compiler is not able to infer that a `Foo` implements `MyTrait` that implements `MetaTrait`?

Comment: Try `impl<T> MetaTrait for T where T: MyTrait`.

Comment: @Tom Regner: probably the title is too generic but this question has to do with trait objects, I don't think it is a duplication.

Comment: @attdona the issue and the possible solutions in the duplicate are the same; `(&jim as &HasBed).sleep();` and `(&jane as &HasTent).sleep();` would also work there.

Comment: Thanks! At first it was not obvious for me. Now it is clear, thanks also to @Tom Regner. I will mark as duplicate.